# Why are strings "0e368798" and "00000000" equal, per PHP's equality operator?

Tags: php, equality

Can someone explain why the following two statements return true?

```
if ('0e368798' == '00000000')
```

or

```
if ((string)'0e368798' == (string)'00000000')
```

Why do I have to use the strict operator to check the equality of these two strings?

Comment: You don't need to typecast, just use ===

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `XeY` is `X * 10^(Y)`, and `0` times anything is `0`. `0000000` is also `0`. And `==` in PHP very intuitively thinks that if it can be converted into a number, it should be.

EDIT: It was in a helpful comment that is now deleted, so with apologies to the commenter whose name I did not catch, I will repeat it here - from [PHP docs on comparison](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically. These rules also apply to the switch statement. The type conversion does not take place when the comparison is === or !== as this involves comparing the type as well as the value.

Comment: Also, I think that `1e368798` falls below the range for IEEE `double`s, so is zero as well. Wait, no, that would be `1e-368798`.

Comment: @JanDvorak: `1e368898` falls *above* it, so it evaluates as `Inf`.

Comment: Thank you. I knew about the XeY format for numbers and also about soft type conversion that takes places during a non-strict comparison. However I was stumped at why typecasting them also did not work. But you cleared that up.